# how using eval in makfile command change macros value with bash variable

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a bash function inside the makefile command and want to change macros value.
Is it possible?

```
C_DFLAGS :=

gui : 
    parse_flags () { echo $$1; for word in $$1; do if [ $${word::2} = -D ] ; then $(eval C_D_FLAGS+=$${word}); fi ; done ; } ; parse_flags "-D/test -D/TEST" 
    @echo "C_D_FLAGS :$(C_D_FLAGS)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(eval)` will be interpreted before your actual bash function call. You cannot update `make` variables from bash - it's a downstream process.

However, the code you try to run is fairly simple to replace with a native syntax, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
C_D_FLAGS :=

gui: C_D_FLAGS += -D/test -D/TEST
gui:
        @echo "C_D_FLAGS: $(C_D_FLAGS)"
$ make gui
C_D_FLAGS: -D/test -D/TEST
```

If the flags are provided from elsewhere, they can also be filtered, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
C_D_FLAGS :=

gui: C_D_FLAGS += $(filter -D%,$(EXTRA_FLAGS))
gui:
        @echo "C_D_FLAGS: $(C_D_FLAGS)"
$ make gui
C_D_FLAGS:
$ make gui EXTRA_FLAGS="-Isomething -DFOO -m32"
C_D_FLAGS: -DFOO
```